# Is there a way to create a simple Markdown wiki with GitHub pages?

Tags: github, markdown, github-pages

I want to use GitHub pages to write and host my own system administration wiki in Markdown.

I already created a repository with myname.github.io and placed in it only one file index.html with the text:

```
Hello world!
```

As the result I want a structured Markdown wiki, for example:

```
index.html
io/mdadm.md
io/lvm.md
io/disks.md
mail/postfix.md
mail/mail.md
bacula/setup.md
bacula/tips.md
bash/tips.md
system/applications/repositories.md
```

When I will navigate to http://myname.github.io I want to see the main page with links to another. I will create the main page in HTML manually.

When I will navigate to http://myname.github.io/system/applications/repositories or something else I want to see rendered Markdown HTML.

How can I create this layout and force GitHub to render Markdown files into HTML?

Is there a better way to use GitHub as a free wiki?

I also understand that I can use standard md files in a repository and default GitHub repository interface. But this interface is over complicated, compared to pure HTML rendered from Markdown.

Comment: Why not use the github wiki? It's markdown

Comment: Ok, but i don't know how to use custom domain for wiki. How to do this ? For example i want that wiki.example.com is point to https://github.com/org/project/wiki

Comment: Maybe try asking github support?

Comment: https://github.com/contact

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Jekyll](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jekyll_%28software%29), the static site generator which works very well with GitHub pages and uses Markdown out of the box.

See [documentation here](https://help.github.com/articles/using-jekyll-with-pages/).